# How should the displacement-time graph be drawn (if anything should be drawn)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, displacement

Let's say I have a particle that goes from A to B, hits a wall at B with velocity $1.4 \mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}$ and starts to go back to A with velocity $-1\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}$ starting from B.

So basically $t=2\mathrm{s}$ when at B.

When I draw the velocity-time graph for the part when it touches B, then leaves B, I will get a straight line with the 2 points $(2,1.4)$ and $(2,-1)$.

The equation of the line being $x=2$.

So how (and should I) represent this on a displacement time-graph?

Comment: Have you tried calculating the displacement at different times and just putting them in a graph to get a better picture of what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

If plotting v versus t, you will also have a horizontal line coming from the left and ending at your first point, and another starting at your second point and going to the right.